# How to disable javaScript in SFSafariViewController?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, sfsafariviewcontroller

We can disable javaScript in WKWebKit using preference.

```
 let preferences = WKPreferences()
 preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
 let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
 configuration.preferences = preferences
 let WebViewKit =  WKWebView(configuration: configuration )
```

But, Is there is any way to disable the javascript in SFSafariViewController?

```
  let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
  config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
  let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: self,configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is NO way to do it. Like what you've mentioned, `WKWebView` has `javaScriptEnabled`.

`SFSafariViewController` must have or gets the user configurations from `Safari`.

To disable it using `Safari`:

> You can disable javascript in Mac OS X Safari by going to
>   Safari->Preferences (Command-,). Click on the Security tab and then
>   uncheck "Enable Javascript". Use the same process to turn javascript
>   back on later.

---

Meanwhile, Apple says in their doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller:

> The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are
>   not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing
>   history, or website data.

Also, based in `SFSafariViewController.h`, you can't do much.

So I guess it's understandable enough that you can't do further than what are there.

Hope it helps.